# configure.ac How to pass string to source code using CPPFLAGS

Tags: c++, c, makefile, autoconf

I want to pass a string to source file from configure.ac using CPPFLAGS

```
./configure.ac --with-path=/a/b/c

AC_ARG_WITH(path, AS_HELP_STRING([--with-path], [Specify path]), [CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS} -DPATH=\\"$withval\\""])
```

The above code is getting translated into

```
-DPATH=/a/b/c
```

What are the changes to be made to get it translated to

```
-DPATH=\"/a/b/c\"
```

Comment: Did you try this ? https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Defining-Symbols.html First part is talking about declaring a quoted defined value